# letter by letter Output Python

Tags: python

is there a way I can let my autofill write letter by letter with a delay to protect from bot detection?

```
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwd"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
password.send_keys(Password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a loop to wait for a second an type slowly:

```
import time

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwd"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')

for char in Password:
    password.send_keys(char)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a for loop, and add a `time.sleep()`

```
for i in Password:
    password.send_keys(i)
    time.sleep(2)
```